# respond_to with custom format aliasing json format, is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, format, respond-to

I have a situation where I'm returning json objects to my application which are built from YML files. Because to parse the yml file and return it as json I always have to do something like this:

```
format.json { render json: YAML.load(render_to_string :file => File.join(Rails.root,'app','views','home','icons.yml.erb'), :layout => false ) }
```

I would like to make this operation shorter, by creating a custom format that (however) result in a json, so I don't want to create a new mime type.

My idea is to write:

```
format.myformat
```

Which will automatically search for *myaction.myformat.erb* inside views/mycontroller directory, and will automatically parse the yaml file returning it as a json object.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I eventually do this?

**Edit 1:**
I found an important suggestion in config/mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :iphone
```

So I **can** alias a mime type, now the biggest problem is: how to define the default render action for a given format, like format.html does?

If I write

```
format.html
```

current_action.html.erb will be automatically rendered, how can I choose the correct method to render a custom format?

**Edit 2:**

I managed to create this code (inside a controller, through some helper methods I built):

```
  def icons
    respond_to do |format|
      format.extjson { render_to_extjson }
    end
  end
```

Is possible to make rails understand that if I write:

```
  def icons
    respond_to do |format|
      format.extjson
    end
  end
```

it has to do:

```
format.extjson { render_to_extjson }
```

by default?

Comment: Have you actually tried doing what you said in Edit2? If you did, what errors did you get?

Comment: it simply renders it by evaluating all erb things and returns the doc as a string, without doing YAML parsing that render_to_extjson does.

Comment: Have you considered using Rails 3 custom responders ? See the very bottom of http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3

Comment: I like the suggestion but still not doing what I'm asking. I'm thinking about aliasing the render method and inject some custom code inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not doable at the moment, I read a lot of rails sources and there isn't a way to access that method, so isn't possible to customize it.

I'll write a rails plugin to support this and eventually I'll post it here, but for sure the answer actually is: **this can't be done**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { @foo = Foo.all(:limit => 10) }
  format.any(:atom, :rss) { @foo = Foo.all }
end
```

A longer post going into the guts of the render actions can be found here: http://ryanbigg.com/2009/04/how-rails-works-2-mime-types-respond_to/

Comment: Mhh that's not exactly what I want, try to see my edit (2) to understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

While Josh's answer is a valid one, I would rather see your parsing code wrapped up into an object. If you put that object into app/models, it'll be testable and you can always verify any change to the logic with a test suite.

Another upside to this is that you can re-use the format.json call and make you controller that much simpler.

Comment: Mh while I like your suggestion, I can't mark it as an answer because doesn't solve my problem. See my edit (2) where I specialized my question